# Uncaught Error: [vuex] actions should be function but "actions.__esModule" is true

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuex

I am new in Vue.js and I want to use `vue boilerplate` from https://github.com/marcosmoura/vue-boilerplate.

When I try to run this using the command `npm run dev` it will generate a link, for example, `http://localhost:8080`.

When I visit this URL in a browser, this error occurs and I am not able to do anything:

[image: error image in chrome browser]

> Uncaught Error: [vuex] actions should be function but "actions.__esModule" is true

Comment: the problem is that `import * as action from './actions'` is also exporting a `__esModule`. Comment that `import` e `actions` use inside `Vuex.Store` and it will work, but I don't know which config defines the existence of `__esModule` :(

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem and solved it by editing `package.json` to change the version of `vuex` to fixed `2.3.0`. Maybe something went wrong in version `2.4.0`.